# How do I access files in a Shared Library?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Shared Library with a .groovy script that I call in a jenkinsfile like this:

```
MySharedLibFunction{ .. some args}
```

I also have a .ps1 file in my shared library I want to execute. But if I do `powershell pwd` from in my shared library function when I call that function from my jenkinsfile the current working directory is the jenkins working directory of my pipeline where the jenkinsfile is located (which is usually what you want).

Is there a way to access files in the shared lib? I want to do `powershell -File ps1FileInMySharedLibVarsFolder.ps1`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can only get the contents using the built-in step `libraryResource`. That's why have the following functions in [my shared library](https://github.com/TYPO3-infrastructure/jenkins-pipeline-global-library-chefci/blob/master/src/org/typo3/chefci/helpers/JenkinsHelper.groovy) to copy it to a temporary directory and return the path to the file:

```java
/**
  * Generates a path to a temporary file location, ending with {@code path} parameter.
  * 
  * @param path path suffix
  * @return path to file inside a temp directory
  */
@NonCPS
String createTempLocation(String path) {
  String tmpDir = pwd tmp: true
  return tmpDir + File.separator + new File(path).getName()
}

/**
  * Returns the path to a temp location of a script from the global library (resources/ subdirectory)
  *
  * @param srcPath path within the resources/ subdirectory of this repo
  * @param destPath destination path (optional)
  * @return path to local file
  */
String copyGlobalLibraryScript(String srcPath, String destPath = null) {
  destPath = destPath ?: createTempLocation(srcPath)
  writeFile file: destPath, text: libraryResource(srcPath)
  echo "copyGlobalLibraryScript: copied ${srcPath} to ${destPath}"
  return destPath
}
```

As it returns the path to the temp file, you can pass this to any step expecting a file name:

```
sh(copyGlobalLibraryScript('test.sh'))
```

for a file residing in `resources/test.sh` within your shared library.

Comment: I also endet up with a solution like this. But it seems quite clumsy to me - I'd prefer something like an option to automatically copy the library (or at least it's 'resource' folder) into workspace...

Comment: Useful but how can we load files from shared library that are inside a folder under resources BUT we don't know neither the number of files neither the files names inside that folder .

Comment: @Roman How did you import just the resources folder into workspace ?

Comment: Done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170409/how-to-load-files-from-resources-folder-in-shared-library-without-knowing-their

Answer (score 5):

stephenking's answer is more complete but for simple cases the following will do:

```
writeFile file: 'ps1FileInMySharedLibVarsFolder.ps1', text: libraryResource('ps1FileInMySharedLibVarsFolder.ps1')
powershell ".\\ps1FileInMySharedLibVarsFolder.ps1"
```