# How can I call a script in the resources folder with arguments in a jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a script I would like to pass arguments and call it like `My-Script.ps1 -arg1 blah -arg2 lkjh`

My script is in the resources folder and I can import and call it like this:

```
def myScript = libraryResource 'PSScripts/My-Script.ps1'
powershell myScript
```

This works as expected, but how can I pass it arguments?

Comment: Doesn't it work to [put the resource file into some temp path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498924/how-do-i-access-files-in-a-shared-library) and then pass its _path_ followed by the parameters to the `powershell` step?

Comment: I'd like to avoid having to copy it somewhere first. I mean I'm already 90% of the way there I just want to pass it args. Besides it looks like it's already putting it in a tmp Jenkins workspace folder before it runs it?

Comment: Jenkins will put everything into temp files anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one approach that can be used.
I ended wrapping my powershell scripts in a function and then using a shared library called `powershellLibraryScript` with the following code:

```
def call(args) {
    args = [
        resource: null,
        script: ""
    ] << args
    def script = libraryResource(args.resource)
    powershell """
$script
# ---------------------------------------------
$args.script
    """
}
```

I then called it with

```
powershellLibraryScript resource: 'MyPowerShellResource.ps1', script: 'MyFunction -Arg1 Value1 -Arg2 Value2'
```

The powershell script can then just be something like

```
function MyFunction() {  
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $arg1 = "value1",

        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $arg2 = "value2"
    )

    # Code...
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, to have a single groovy function that can call any of the PS scripts in the resources dir. I like it. Two questions, is there a specific reason for the commented line of dashes? What is the mechanism of the `$script` followed by `$args.script` and what does it do? Thanks.