# How to load files from resources folder in Shared library without knowing their names (or number)?

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

As you know, in Shared libraries in Jenkins, it is possible to load a resource (located in resources folder) by doing:

```groovy
libraryResource("script.sh")
```

Now my use case is that I want to load number of files inside a folder under resources :

```
+ resources
 + teamA
  + script1.sh
  + script2.sh
```

And I want to load all those files before doing anything : 
I did a method in the shared library:

```groovy
new File(scriptsFolder).eachFile() { file->

 writeFile([file:"${env.workspace}/${file.getName()}",text:libraryResource("$scriptsFolder/${file.getName()}")])
 sh("chmod +x ${env.workspace}/${file.getName()}")
}
```

where `scriptsFolder= "teamA"`

Of cource I'm getting `java.io.IOException: Is a directory`
Because `libraryResource` must get a file path parameter.

So is, there a way to load all those files without knowing their names or their number?

Comment: May be a checkout just for resources folder ? how ? Any more elegant way ?

Answer (score 12):

You can get absolute path of your shared library using Groovy @SourceURI annotation:

```
// vars/get_resource_dir.groovy
import groovy.transform.SourceURI
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.Paths

class ScriptSourceUri {
    @SourceURI
    static URI uri
}

def call() {
    Path scriptLocation = Paths.get(ScriptSourceUri.uri)
    return scriptLocation.getParent().getParent().resolve('resources').toString()
}
```

Using the path you can invoke your scripts as usual:

```
sh "${get_resource_dir()}/com/example/test.sh"
```

Comment: This looked like the ideal solution to my problem... Except that this triggers two security exceptions:  
1) "Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod java.net.URI create java.lang.String."  
2) "Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod java.nio.file.Paths get java.net.URI."  
And the second is red-flagged by Jenkins as "Approving this signature may introduce a security vulnerability! You are advised to deny it."  
I can't take that risk :-(

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the power of shell scripting. Jenkins server and slaves are all on Linux.

given: I am in a sub-directory, and the resources folder is one directory up.

```
String folder = "resources/teamA"
sh(script: "cp -R ../${folder}/. .")

// Verify files
def status = steps.sh(script: "diff ../${folder}/ .", returnStatus : true)

if(status.equals(0)) {
    // do that thing you do
} else {
    error "FAILURE not all files required exist"
}
```